# Django, nginx, how i can return another type of file?

Tags: django, nginx

I have django project,in this project i have static file, this file is exist in `/media/` folder

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/'
```

The file is exist by link https://supersite.com/apple-app-site-association but this file is has type `application/octet-stream` and i need return type `application/pkcs7-mime;`

My nginx settings is contains

```
 location /media/ {
                autoindex on;
                alias /media/;
                default_type application/pkcs7-mime;
            }

location /media/apple-app-site-association {
        autoindex on;
        default_type application/pkcs7-mime;
    }


    location = /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        default_type application/pkcs7-mime;
    }
```

but return file still `application/octet-stream`. How i can change type of file on `application/pkcs7-mime` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your media configuration should be this to match the configuration of your nginx:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

You can edit `/etc/nginx/mime.types` and add the type:

```
types {
    application/pkcs7-mime        pkcs7;
}
```

Then in your nginx configuration:

```
location = /media/ {
    autoindex on;
    default_type pkcs7;
}
```